# Wordpress- Add script directly to page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

How can I add my script directly to my page instead of putting it in `<head>` or `<footer>`? For example,

```
<div>
    My script here
    My html
    My html
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script`, add it to a function you hook onto `wp_enqueue_scripts` in your `functions.php` file https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: this question seems better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks I will ask there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not the WordPress way and is not advised but it can be done ... that's for sure.

The normal way how to do this (is to include/enqueue the js or css file, using *wp_enqueue_style* function to enqueue css files and *wp_enqueue_script* to enqueue js files. Proper documentation on how to use those functions can be found on the WordPress Coding reference guide if you search on the internet.

If you want to add your script just to one of your pages/posts, etc ... you can do the old way by inserting the script tag inside the post like this:

< script scr="script-src">< /script>

if the script is not external, is just some small functionality you want to add then you can simply use:

< script>alert('hello world');< /script>

These scripts cant be added on the backend side ... they need to be added on the theme's code ...

Remove all extra spaces i had to add here because of the script tags being filtered for security measures.

Hope i have helped you to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: Yes I want to add the script to one of my pages only

Comment: When I try to insert the script tag inside my page, It gets converted to <p><script>xxxx</script></p>

Comment: Are you inserting this in the backend side of wp or in code directly? Im guessing you are enter <script></script> in the backend ... if so then i have to say that you should only add the script by editing the theme file ...

Another thing you could try is to switch on to the Text editor not the Visual editor and add there the script you want to add ...

Since this is something against the wordpress way i havent tried it myself but it might work.

Comment: How can I my script affect only one page?

Comment: Then edit page.php or single.php and add there the script you want to add ... you better put an if check to check and select only the page where you want your script to get executed for or you could do this ... if you are trying to add this script only to the page with id 400 for example then copy/paste page.php, rename it to page-400.php and add there the script. this way you add this script only to the page with id 400 ... same thing for posts (only copy/paste single.php)

Comment: Thanks a ton Arber!..sounds promising, will give it a try now :)

Answer (score -1):

Its the same, use

```
<script>
    xxxxxxx
</script>
```

Comment: It doesnt work..It somehow gets converted to <p><script>xxxx</script></p>